# Rotating UILabel is clipping text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cgaffinetransform

I have a `UILabel` that I am trying to rotate.  First I am calling `sizeToFit` on the label, adding a little padding to the frame and then setting the transform to `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)` (where `rotation` is a value calculated from a UIRotationGestureRecognizer).

Some of the text is being clipped as the `UILabel` is rotated (as illustrated in the image linked below).  For demonstrative purposes, I made the UILabel's background color red so you can see how the bounds change when it is rotated.  How do I prevent this from happening?

http://cl.ly/image/3F0M420R0d14

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this line to rotate your label [label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2)];

Comment: Show us some code and we'll be able to help more. My guess is that you are changing the frame after you apply the rotate transform and this screws up the label. If this is the case, consider using         CGAffineTransformConcat to apply both rotation and scale transforms in one step. My guess.

Comment: Horatiu, you're correct.  It seems as though a UIPinchGestureRecognizer that scales the same label is causing the problem.  The label rotates as expected when I disable the pinch.

Comment: When pinching/scaling the label I call `sizeToFit`.  When scaling do I need to temporarily remove the rotation transform, call `sizeToFit` and then re-apply the transform?